# Terraform Plan resulting in stream error: stream ID 1; INTERNAL_ERROR when creating EKS Cluster

Tags: terraform, cluster-computing, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to create EKS cluster with Terraform but while running the script, i am getting the below error:

```
│ Error: query: failed to query with labels: stream error when reading response body, may be caused by closed connection. Please retry. Original error: stream error: stream ID 1; INTERNAL_ERROR
│
│   with helm_release.cert-manager,
│   on helm.tf line 54, in resource "helm_release" "cert-manager":
│   54: resource "helm_release" "cert-manager" {
```

- following is an entry from line 54 of helm.tf:

```
resource "helm_release" "cert-manager" {
  name = "jetstack"
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart = "cert-manager"
  namespace = "cert-manager"
  create_namespace = true
  version = "v1.5.5"

  values = [
    "${file("helm-values/cert-manager.yml")}"
  ]
}
```

following is the error from debug log:

```
2023-05-16T09:49:35.354+0530 [WARN]  Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm" produced an invalid plan for helm_release.external-dns, 
but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
    The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
      - .atomic: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .dependency_update: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .force_update: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_crd_hooks: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .recreate_pods: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .skip_crds: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .wait_for_jobs: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .render_subchart_notes: planned value cty.True for a non-computed attribute
      - .replace: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .cleanup_on_fail: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_webhooks: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .lint: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .wait: planned value cty.True for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_openapi_validation: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .max_history: planned value cty.NumberIntVal(0) for a non-computed attribute
      - .reset_values: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .reuse_values: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .timeout: planned value cty.NumberIntVal(300) for a non-computed attribute
      - .verify: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
2023-05-16T09:49:37.975+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5.exe: 2023/05/16 09:49:37 [DEBUG] [resourceDiff: autoscaler] Got chart: timestamp=2023-05-16T09:49:37.975+0530
2023-05-16T09:49:37.975+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5.exe: 2023/05/16 09:49:37 [DEBUG] [resourceDiff: autoscaler] Release validated: timestamp=2023-05-16T09:49:37.975+0530
2023-05-16T09:49:37.976+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5.exe: 2023/05/16 09:49:37 [DEBUG] [resourceDiff: autoscaler] Done: timestamp=2023-05-16T09:49:37.975+0530
2023-05-16T09:49:37.977+0530 [WARN]  Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm" produced an invalid plan for helm_release.cluster-autoscaler, but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
    The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
      - .recreate_pods: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .render_subchart_notes: planned value cty.True for a non-computed attribute
      - .replace: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .skip_crds: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .wait_for_jobs: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .cleanup_on_fail: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_webhooks: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .lint: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_openapi_validation: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .max_history: planned value cty.NumberIntVal(0) for a non-computed attribute
      - .reset_values: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .wait: planned value cty.True for a non-computed attribute
      - .reuse_values: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .timeout: planned value cty.NumberIntVal(300) for a non-computed attribute
      - .verify: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .atomic: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .dependency_update: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_crd_hooks: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .force_update: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
2023-05-16T09:49:38.037+0530 [INFO]  backend/local: plan operation completed
╷
│ Error: query: failed to query with labels: stream error when reading response body, may be caused by closed connection. Please retry. Original error: stream error: stream ID 1; INTERNAL_ERROR
│
│   with helm_release.cert-manager,
│   on helm.tf line 54, in resource "helm_release" "cert-manager":
│   54: resource "helm_release" "cert-manager" {
│
```

There is a 10mins timeout configured on the tasks but still getting this issue.

Can some one tell is going wrong here or why am i getting this issue.

I tried to update the cert manager version that did not work.
configured 10 mins of timeout as well.